# change list name in for loop 'header'

Tags: python, numpy

probably a very simple question:
How to change a list name in the for loop 'header'?
For example, in the next piece of code the number '4' comes from a user defined variable 'N', so instead of looking like this:

```
for tr in st_**4**:
    tr.data = np.require(tr.data, dtype=np.float32)
```

I would like  to establish the dependency with 'N', for example:

```
for tr in st_**N**:
    tr.data = np.require(tr.data, dtype=np.float32)
```

but I can not find what is the right way to write this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't. This is a bad pattern. Use a dictionary (or list) to hold your variables, and access the values by key or position.

Comment: `lst = [str_1, str_2, …] ; for tr in lst: ...` or `d = {'str_3': …, 'str_4': …} ; for tr in range(1, 5): d[f'str_{N}'].data = …` as a general outline